# Installing packages in R, got errors

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to install these packages but I am coming up with the errors below.

> install.packages("ggplot2")
>       Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Harshal/Dropbox/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
>       (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>       trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/ggplot2_2.2.1.zip'
>       Content type 'application/zip' length 2760173 bytes (2.6 MB)
>       downloaded 2.6 MB

```
package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Harshal\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpclmjoS\downloaded_packages
> install.packages("ggplot")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Harshal/Dropbox/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘ggplot’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)
> install.packages("ggplot2")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Harshal/Dropbox/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/ggplot2_2.2.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2760173 bytes (2.6 MB)
downloaded 2.6 MB

package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Harshal\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpclmjoS\downloaded_packages
> install.packages("lazyeval")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Harshal/Dropbox/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
         binary source needs_compilation
lazyeval  0.2.0  0.2.1              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/lazyeval_0.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 138952 bytes (135 KB)
downloaded 135 KB

package ‘lazyeval’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Harshal\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpclmjoS\downloaded_packages
> install.packages("lazyeval")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Harshal/Dropbox/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
         binary source needs_compilation
lazyeval  0.2.0  0.2.1              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/lazyeval_0.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 138952 bytes (135 KB)
downloaded 135 KB

package ‘lazyeval’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Harshal\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpclmjoS\downloaded_packages
> install.packages("colorspace")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Harshal/Dropbox/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/colorspace_1.3-2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 439560 bytes (429 KB)
downloaded 429 KB

package ‘colorspace’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Harshal\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpclmjoS\downloaded_packages
> install.packages("plyr")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Harshal/Dropbox/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/plyr_1.8.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1121290 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

package ‘plyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Harshal\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpclmjoS\downloaded_packages
> library("ggplot")
Error in library("ggplot") : there is no package called ‘ggplot’
> library("ggplot2")
Warning message:
package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
> library("lazyeval")
Warning message:
package ‘lazyeval’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
> library("colorspace")
Warning message:
package ‘colorspace’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
> library("plyr")
Warning message:
package ‘plyr’ was built under R version 3.2.5
```

Comment: The only error is when you typed `ggplot` instead of `ggplot2`. The others are just warnings, letting you know that the packages were built using a newer version of R than your current installation. Probably it won't cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced same issue with R version 3.4.1. Try devtools::install_github("").

If this did not fix your issue you may be running into another error such as this:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
```

there is no package called ‘bindrcpp’

In addition:

```
Warning message: package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 3.4.4
```

To address this issue install the "bindrcpp" package 
install.packages("bindrcpp"). I had to repeat this step for the "mnormt" and "cellranger" packages. Hope this helps!